# Angular 5 Reactive form Cannot find control with path: 'addAmendmentGroups -> 0 -> addAmendmentArrayId'

Tags: angular, angular5, ngfor, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create a form where a user can add multiple amendments to a main contribution by . I have followed the Angular Reactive Forms demo [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#use-formarray-to-present-an-array-of-formgroups) and am using a `FormArray` populated via the model, and looped in `ngFor`in the HTML to repeat the controls on the form.
I get the following errors when the page loads.

`Cannot find control with path: 'addAmendmentGroups -> 0 -> addAmendmentArrayId'
Cannot find control with path: 'addAmendmentGroups -> 0 -> memberId'`

When I click the + button to add more controls to the page I get the same errors but for every control. I'm sure there is something I'm missing, or does this not work for Angular5?
Aside: Yes, I know `addAmendmentGroups` is a terrible name for a FormArray.

**Model.ts**

```
export class Contribution {
  amendments: Amendment[];
}

export class Amendment {
  addAmendmentArrayId: number;
  listType: ListType;
  numberReference: number;
  whiteListId: number;
  whiteListReference: number;
  memberId: number[];
}

export enum ListType {
  Numbered = 0,
  White = 1
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class AmendmentFormComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  contribution: Contribution;

  form: FormGroup;

  public amendmentView: string;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { this.createForm(); }

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};
  propagateTouch = (_: any) => {};

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      listType: 0,

      addAmendmentGroups: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          addAmendmentGroupId: 0,
          listType: 0,
          numberedListReference: [{ value: 0, disabled: false }, Validators.required],
          whiteListId: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
          whiteListNumberReference: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
          memberName: ['', Validators.required]
        })
      ]),
      foobar: ''
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.rebuildForm();
  }

  rebuildForm() {
    this.form.reset({
      listType: 0,
      foobar:''
    });
    this.setAmendments(this.contribution.amendments);
  }

  get addAmendmentGroups(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('addAmendmentGroups') as FormArray;
  }

  setAmendments(amendments: Amendment[]) {
    const amendmentFGs = amendments.map(amendment => this.fb.group(amendment));
    const amendmentFormArray = this.fb.array(amendmentFGs || []);
    this.form.setControl('addAmendmentGroups',amendmentFormArray);
  }
  addAmendment() {
    this.addAmendmentGroups.push(this.fb.group(new Amendment()));
  }
}
```

**Component.html**

```
<div class="content">
  <p>Form Value:{{ form.value | json }}</p>
  <h4 class="content-title">Add amendment</h4>
  Amendment View Id :<strong>{{ amendmentView }}</strong>
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="addAmendmentGroups">
      <div *ngFor="let amendment of form.controls.addAmendmentGroups.controls; let i = index" >
        <div [formGroupName]="i">

          <input type="text" formControlName="addAmendmentArrayId" value="{{addAmendmentArrayId}}">
          <div class="row form-item">
            <div class="col-lg-2 item-instance">
              <ul class="radio-list">
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" formControlName="listType" [value]="0" name="listType" checked data-test="listTypeNumbered" tabindex="1" />
                  <span>Numbered List</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" formControlName="listType" [value]="1" name="listType" data-test="listTypeWhite" tabindex="3" />
                  <span>Whitelist</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          Index={{i}}<br />
          <input type="text" formControlName="numberedListReference" [placeholder]="NUMBEREDLISTREFERENCE" data-test="numberedListReference" tabindex="2" />Reference
          <input type="number" formControlName="whiteListId" />
          <input type="text" formControlName="whiteListNumberReference" [placeholder]="WHITELISTREFERENCE" data-test="whiteListNumberReference" tabindex="5" />White
          <input type="number" formControlName="memberId" />
          <!--<oir-amendment-group [formControlName]="i"></oir-amendment-group>-->
          <br />
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="foobar" value="" id="" />
    <button (click)="addAmendment()">+</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Update:**
I have fixed the reference errors between my model and component and that has resolved the errors on load. I updated my component to push the `formGroup` when the Add button is clicked. However this just pushes the existing form group, not a new instance of the form group.

```
createForm() {
    this.amendmentForm = this.fb.group({
      //addAmendmentArrayId: 0,
      listType: 0,
      numberReference: [{ value: 0, disabled: false }, Validators.required],
      whiteListId: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
      whiteListReference: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
      memberId: ['', Validators.required]
    })
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      addAmendmentGroups: this.fb.array([
        this.amendmentForm
      ]),
      foobar: ''
    });
}
  addAmendment() {
this.addAmendmentGroups.push(this.amendmentForm);
```

}
Is there any way to push a new instance of the amendmentForm into the formArray, I know I can push an instance of the model with `this.addAmendmentGroups.push(new Amendment())` but this doesn't allow field validation.

Answer (score 2):

`addAmendmentArrayId` and `memberId` doesn't exist on your form.

```
this.fb.group({
          addAmendmentGroupId: 0,
          listType: 0,
          numberedListReference: [{ value: 0, disabled: false }, Validators.required],
          whiteListId: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
          whiteListNumberReference: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
          memberName: ['', Validators.required]
        })
```

If I read your template, your formgroup in your formarray should be

```
 this.fb.group({
          addAmendmentArrayId : 0,
          addAmendmentGroupId: 0,
          listType: 0,
          numberedListReference: [{ value: 0, disabled: false }, Validators.required],
          whiteListId: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
          whiteListNumberReference: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
          memberName: ['', Validators.required],
          memberId: ['', Validartors.required]
        })
```

EDIT : I don't know if that's you want, but your model is very different than your formgroup.

Based on your model from `Model.ts`, your formgroup shoudn't be like this ?

```
 this.fb.group({
      addAmendmentArrayId: 0,
      listType: 0,
      numberReference: [{ value: 0, disabled: false }, Validators.required],
      whiteListId: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
      whiteListReference: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
      memberId: ['', Validators.required]
    })
```

Comment: You're right, don't know how I didn't spot those mis-matches. I have fixed those and that has resolved most of the errors. I was still getting an error with the `listType` control when I clicked the Add button, but I've found if I explicitly push the fields this resolves the error. `addAmendment() { this.addAmendmentGroups.push(this.amendmentForm);}`. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Pushing this.amendmentForm doesn't work as I hoped, I've updated my question to reflect this.